# What is the difference between Google Maps ATM symbols?

Tags: android, google-maps

When I search on Google Maps for ATMs two different symbols appear to show the location of the money machines. What is the difference between this symbols? What do they indicate?

[image: ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "money" icons indicate a *bank* which also happens to have an ATM at the same place.

The "ATM" icon indicates a standalone ATM.